# Existence of a continuous function between $T_2$ and $T_1$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\;T_1=S_1\times S_1$ and $\;T_2=S_1\times D_1$ where $S_1$ is the unitary circle and $D_1$ the unitary disc (so $T_1$ is an "empty" torus and $T_2$ is a "full" one).

$T_1$ and $T_2$ are both subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (with the standard topology).

Let $i:T_1\hookrightarrow T_2$ be the inclusion.

Is there a continuous function $r:T_2\rightarrow T_1$ such that $\;r\circ i = \text{Id}_{T_1}$?

---

I am not sure where to start, any hint?

Comment: Think about the fundamental groups.

Comment: have you heard of the $\pi_1$ functor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose such an $r$ does exist. Recall that $\pi_1(T_1)\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(T_2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ (because $T_2$ is homotopy equivalent to a circle). From induced maps, we have $$\pi_1(T_1) \stackrel{i_*}{\rightarrow} \pi_1(T_2) \stackrel{r_*}{\rightarrow}\pi_1(T_1)$$ should be equal to $Id_{\pi_1(T_1)}\colon \pi_1(T_1) \rightarrow\pi_1(T_1)$. Given the groups $\pi_1(T_1)$ and $\pi_1(T_2)$ above, can you see how such a factoring of the identity isomorphism is not possible? In particular, consider the kernel of $i_*$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it from there.